# password hasing with php hash_hmac

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

Existing Approach:

```
//$user_id = $row['UserID']; User Identifier
//$token = uniqid($user_id,TRUE);
//$salt = md5(mt_rand());
//$cookie_id = hash_hmac('SHA512',$token,$salt);

$expiry = strval(time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
$cookie_name = "GETIN";
//Store these data in DB
setcookie("GETIN",$token,$expiry);
```

This is how i am generating cookie values and only setting `uniqid of userID and expiry time in client side`

And when user logs in next time,

```
        $cookie_name = 'GETIN';
        $salt = getSalt($cookie_name,$connection);
        $cookie_id = getCookieID($cookie_name,$connection);
        echo "      cookieid=".$cookie_id ;
        echo "      salt=".$salt;
        if($cookie_id == (hash_hmac('SHA512',$_COOKIE['GETIN'],$salt)))
        {
            die('{"status":"success"}');
        }
```

This is how i am checking the status.

What are the problems with this approach? Please let me know the problem with this type of cookie mechanism

Comment: probably fit for code review instead.

Comment: I am not posting my entire code here and can i post this question there?

Comment: I'd say you're probably better off posting it on code review, seeing you're asking if there are problems with an "approach/method".

Comment: I must delete this question, right? Otherwise it would be repeated one.

Comment: after seeing your other question, well I guess that would be "no", since you've linked to this page in there

Comment: Yes, Can you please clear my doubt of that question?